# How to add trailing 0s without a decimal

Tags: excel

I have accounting codes. Some are 4 digits which end in 0's and others are 12 digits longs.

I formatted cells in a column on an Excel spreadsheet, that I use for coding bills, masked as "0000-0000-0000".

However, sometimes i might only have an account number with 4 digits and ends in 0s or it might have 12 digits. Either way, it's 12 digits.

Is there custom format so that I don't need to type all the trailing 0s for those which have only 4 or 8 digits leading digits?

Ex. I want to type 1200 and my cell spits out 1200-0000-0000 without having to type 120000000000.

Comment: is this excel, or dynamics?

Comment: I apologize, It's Excel.

Comment: When you're typing in a cell, how do you want Excel to know if that 4 digit number should immediately have 0s added on, or whether to wait for you to type out all 12 digits?

Comment: There is no custom format in Excel to do that.  You can either use an adjacent column with a formula, or you can write a VBA event macro to accomplish what you want.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - I was surprised at this. I thought you could do a format of either `0000-0000-0000` or `####-0000-0000` would do it, but alas that puts the `1200` at the *end*. Good call.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem you have is that by default numbers don't work that way. If you type 12 in an excel cell, excel will think it's twelve, not 120 billion.

Paste this formula in cell B1:

```
=NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(A1&"00000000000", 12))
```

Set B1's format to custom `0000-0000-0000`

Type 12 into cell A1. B1 becomes what you ask

It works because the formula concatenates 11 zeroes (as a string) onto the value you typed, then trims it down to just the 12 leftmost characters and turns it back into a number.

> 12 -> "**120000000000**0" -> "120000000000" -> 1200-0000-0000